# Preload / Autobuffer Media Element HTML5 on iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, html, video, preload

I don't think iOS can handle preload / autobuffer of html5 videos. Is this correct, or can anyone else tell me how they've managed to do it?

Clarification:
I want the content of the video to begin downloading before the play button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Is it do do with this: [how to get your HTML5 MP4 video file to play before being fully downloaded](http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2011/03/html5/how-to-get-your-html5-mp4-video-file-to-play-before-being-fully-downloaded)? As it usually is.

Comment: I see how you could interpret my question that way, and that link is interesting. That's not what I meant though. I want the content of the video to begin downloading before the play button is clicked.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well the only way is via preload as you've mentioned. I've not heard of it not working on iOS though.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Some mobile devices like iOS devices will not preload the video in order to protect their users' bandwidth. Same restriction for the same reason to autoplay attribute